# Locally developing NextJS and fetch getting self signed cert error

Tags: next.js

I'm new to NextJS.  I'm writing an app using NextJS for the front end and .NET Core API on the back end.

Usually, I can have visual studio create a self signed cert to run my apis with SSL and then have front end apps use that self signed cert to run things locally (at least I've done this with Angular without any issues).

I'm not sure how to do this with NextJS.  My fetch command in my nextjs API, is failing because of the self-signed cert.  Is there an easy way to tell NextJS that while I'm running localhost, ignore that a self signed cert is in the chain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you haven't already you need to setup a custom local server for NextJS because it doesn't support local development with SSL out of the box. [Here is a guide on how to do that.](https://blog.wbgneto.com/how-to-set-up-local-ssl-with-nextjs) This is a [highly requested](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/33768) feature for NextJS.

Update Jan 2024:

As of NextJS 13.5.1 you can use https with the flag `--experimental-https`

Comment: I dont get why this is voted up  - its not answered the question.  Its not about putting ssl on nextjs server. its a problem with nextresponse.rewrite ect where it cannot rewrite/proxy the request to a servicer with a selfsigned cert.

Comment: @PoulK.Sørensen The original poster was asking how they could prevent their fetch request failing locally with NextJS. NextJS is a full stack framework and doesn't feature a way to run the server locally using an SSL which was causing the requests to fail because the posters backend was expecting secure requests.

Comment: Hey, I have a question about this. I run my projects in external hard drives and for some reason I can run the https from there, only when the project is on my main HD, any idea?

Comment: @NormanPleitez That sounds like something you'd be better off asking about with more details as its own question.

Comment: @iicaptain I did, I was just trying to search more if someone else knows. Maybe if you want to take a look at it. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77901327/experimental-https-in-next-js-doesnt-work-if-i-run-dev-from-a-external-hd

Answer (score 8):

I was running into the same error when developing a front-end NextJS and trying to connect it with a .NET Core API.

```
error - FetchError: request to https://localhost:7291/product/all failed, reason: self signed certificate
```

The way I fixed this problem was configuring my .NET Core API to not redirect requests to HTTPS.
Inside my Program.cs file, I only removed the line 'app.UseHttpsRedirection()' and it worked perfectly. No more errors.

```
var app = builder.Build();
{
    app.UseCors();
    // app.UseHttpsRedirection(); 
    app.MapControllers();
    app.Run();
}
```

I hope it work for you, too.
I found the solution for this here:
[How to Disable SSL on ASP.NET Core 5 Project in Visual Studio 2022?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70785701/how-to-disable-ssl-on-asp-net-core-5-project-in-visual-studio-2022)

PS: Also, if you have configured some CORS policy, don't forget to pass it in app.UseCors(my_CORS_policy).

Answer (score 5):

As of version 13.5.0 there's experimental support for this feature.

Update your package.json script with the following: 
`next dev --experimental-https`

It will generate certificates for localhost using [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert).
If you've written your own backend separately using something like NodeJS or NestJS, etc. and have already generated local SSL certificates, replace them with the ones generated by NextJS and update your paths. Both client and API must use the same certificates.

More info via Github [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10935)

Answer (score 1):

There is now experimental support for this at release 13.5.4 of NextJS.