# How to Disable SSL on ASP.NET Core 5 Project in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2022

How to Disable SSL on ASP.NET Core 5 Project in Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 11):

In Startup.cs try removing

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

from the index method inside the home controller

[RequireHttps]

Comment: This disables Https redirection, but it still tries to configure SSL and fails if you don't have a cert.

Answer (score 9):

In the projects debug settings there is a "Use SSL" checkbox.

Menu Debug | (Project Name) Debug Properties is one route to the settings. Editing `launchSettings.json` would be another.

Comment: If you are using `VS2022` with `dotnet 6.0` app, then Go to `Project Settings > Debug > General > Open debug launch profiles UI > IIS Express` then uncheck `Use SSL`

Answer (score 7):

In Program.cs remove

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

and In Debug option of the project, click the "Open debug launch profiles UI" link and untick the Use SSL under IIS Express

Comment: This answer appears to be comprised of the two previous answers.

Comment: This is not working for me in VS 2022. Are there any other settings that should be changed?

Comment: Never mind, I forgot to switch the active configuration from https to http. Noob mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Building on comment from Muhammad Ummar...

If you are using VS2022 with dotnet 6.0 app, then Go to Project Settings > Debug > General > Open debug launch profiles UI > IIS Express then uncheck Use SSL

I also needed to edit the App Url remove the https utl from:
Project Settings > Debug > General > Open debug launch profiles UI > "Project name" > App Url

Answer (score 2):

If you are using VS2022 with dotnet 6.0 app, Go to Project Settings > Debug > General > Open debug launch profiles UI

1. in "IIS Express" then uncheck Use SSL
2. Remove the https url from "App URL" of the project

Comment: Sorry duplicated with above