# ERROR: self-signed certificate in certificate chain in NextJS 14

Tags: next.js, https, planetscale

I'm using `NextJS 14.0.4` to connect with my planetscale database using mysql2 package. The connection worked fine when my database secrets were hard coded. When I placed my secrets in .env.local file. The localhost gives error "Error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain". Although it still works fine on my vercel deployment.

I already tried adding `--experimental-https` to my dev script and install the mkcert certificates following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70440486/locally-developing-nextjs-and-fetch-getting-self-signed-cert-error) yet the issue still persists.
My database connection code

```js
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST,
    user: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_USERNAME,
    database: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATABASE,
    password: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PASSWORD,
    waitForConnections: true,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    maxIdle: 10, // max idle connections, the default value is the same as `connectionLimit`
    idleTimeout: 60000, // idle connections timeout, in milliseconds, the default value 60000
    queueLimit: 0,
    enableKeepAlive: true,
    keepAliveInitialDelay: 0,
    ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
    },
})
```

I need to keep ssle rejectUnauthorized: true as it is required by planetscale.